# How to read from solr index?

Tags: php, solr

I index my db table directly into solr according to this documentation http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DIHQuickStart

The full import works. However when I query data like this I get
no result

```
   $solr = new Apache_Solr_Service('localhost', '8983', 'solr/');

   $offset = 0;
   $limit = 1000;

   $queries = array(
      'details:Server'
   );

   $response = $solr->search( $query, $offset, $limit );
```

Solr itself is running. I try to query the row "details" but it gives me now result.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Schema.xml : http://pastebin.com/2kx7MkDX

data-config.xml : http://pastebin.com/vtDZzuqC

solrconfig.xml : http://pastebin.com/V6nzvMa5

all from /example/solr/conf/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your answer:

Your 'details' field is defined as 'string'. In Solr, it means it's indexed as a single literal token. The 'string' type is usually used for identifiers.

Therefore, your query 'details:Server' would **ONLY** match the documents where 'details' *exactly* equals 'Server', and **NOT** the document where 'details' contains 'Server'.

Change your 'details' field to something that will index your text as separate words (tokens):

```
<field name="details" type="text" ...
<!-- for instance -->
```

And re-index everything. You might also want to review your other fields definitions.

I encourage you to read the default type definitions in your schema.xml.

Answer (score 2):

Should

```
$solr = new Apache_Solr_Service('localhost', '8983', 'solr/');
```

be

```
$solr = new Apache_Solr_Service('localhost', '8983', '/solr');
```

Comment: hm this does not help me, solr itself is running well. I looked at the index manully and all the data is there. The query returns just stdClass Object ( [numFound] => 0 [start] => 0 [docs] => Array ( ) )

Answer (score 1):

add to data-config.xml

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource"
             driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
             url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/admin_pproject"
             user="root"
             password=""/>
  <document>
    <entity name="id"
           query="select id, name,details, owner, subtype, edit, sub, type, provision, active from programme">

           <!-- ADD-->         
           <field column="id" name="id"/>
           <field column="name" name="name" />
           <field column="details" name="details" />
           <field column="owner" name="owner" />
           <field column="subtype" name="subtype" />
           <field column="edit" name="edit" />
           <field column="sub" name="sub" />
           <field column="type" name="type" />
           <field column="provision" name="provision" />
           <field column="active" name="active" />


        </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

test

Answer (score 0):

We probably need to see your schema.xml. There may be an error there in it.

What happens if you search for "server" with a lower case "s"?

If that fixes it, you have an analysis problem, look in schema.xml.

You can also look in the schema browser (follow the link on the admin page). Click to the "details" field (on the left), and look at the 1000 or 10000 terms, and see if you see the word "server" (or "Server"). What you see will tell you if the word is in the index (at least, if you have less than 10,000 unique words in the field).

Comment: thanks for your answer. However, for both server and Server there is no search result. But Server is in the index (for now I have 90 terms). I remember some days ago before I started indexing the db directly it worked for me with the code above, but now It just gives me no result. I edited my question with the sourcecodes. please have a look at it.